# Change color of links in NUnit Test Runner in Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, themes, nunit, resharper, appearance

I prefer to use the dark theme in Visual Studio, but one source of annoyance is the links in Resharper's nUnit Test Runner. I've looked everywhere, but I can't seem to find the option to change to get them to display properly.

Specifically, this the Unit Test Session window, the Output tab, when you have a stack trace and it has a link on it, it currently appears in the default dark blue, which is fine on a white/grey background...however on the black background, it looks horrible and is near impossible to read.

Does anyone know the option to change the color of that link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three settings relevant to stack trace hyperlinks. Resharper hyperlinks the type, method and physical path on disk. The relevant settings under `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Fonts and Colours` are:

- Type hyperlink - `Stack Trace Type`
- Method hyperlink - `Stack Trace Method`
- Physical path hyperlink - `Stack Trace Path`

[image: Visual Studio Colour Option for Stack Traces]

Edit: Resharper Ultimate 2016.2 seems to have renamed these to include "Resharper" prefix:

[image: Visual Studio Colour Option for Stack Traces (Reshaper 2016.2)]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the `ReSharper Hyperlink` colour under Visual Studio->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Fonts and Colors` ?

[image]